# Spring Boot Not picking up Environment Variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Developing on Windows 10, using Spring Boot 1.4.2 Release.
I just added a environment variable `DATABASE_HOST` into my System variables and I'm trying to read it in my `application.properties` as below:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${DATABASE_HOST}/sampleTable?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&requireSSL=false
```

But after running the application the jdbc throws an exception. Isn't `${xxx}` the way to read from system environment variables?

Comment: Yes it is, but is it not that spring should be reading this variable rather than you?

Comment: @Prashant Shouldn't I still pass it the right variable name?

Comment: No, Spring will pick it up automatically. Please refer to [Working with SQL databases](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html)

Comment: Open up a terminal and type `echo %DATABASE_HOST%`. What do you see? BTW, Spring Boot should be able to read that env var and inject it in your URL.

Comment: @AliDehghani it returns the correct db host value.

Comment: What is the exception that is being thrown?

Comment: Restart the machine !! I am struggling with the same issue